# typescript use es6 as target but node not support "import" keyword

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get this to work in VSCode, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. 
I just want to use `Generator` in Typescript with VSCode, but i found that the nodejs can't support keyword "import" . 
If use "ES5" as target in tsconfig.json, typescript can't support Generator in VSCode. 
Here is demo:

```
// typescript app.ts
import * as http from "http";

http.createServer((request, response) => {  
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write("Hello World!");  
    response.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

And then get this

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import * as http from "http";
http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    response.write("Hello World!");
    response.end();
}).listen(8000);
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

run by `node --harmony app.js` or `node --harmony_modules app.js` all get:

```
g:\Temp\TypeScriptTest>node --harmony app.js
g:\Temp\TypeScriptTest\app.js:2
import * as http from "http";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Or use

```
import http = require("http"); // ES5 require module style
```

VSCode warning

```
Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"' or 'import d from "mod"' instead.
```

Has some way to typescript compile *.ts file use `ES6` style import module and I can use `ES6` features such as `Generator` in Typescript?

Comment: The node version is 4.1.2

Comment: I think you need to drop one feature, for now or may be try babel like ts -> es6 -> babel?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is one way to resolved, and then I can write one tool to replace all the import statement to `var ns = require("mod")` after tsc compile the *.ts.

Comment: Both Nodejs 4.1.x and Typescript support some ES6 features/syntactic, 
tsc compile *.ts in es6 can't run in Node will make people feel very tangled, Especially the beginning of the import statement

Answer (score 1):

> Has some way to typescript compile *.ts file use ES6 style import module and I can use ES6 features such as Generator in Typescript?

You need to target `es6` and then pass the output through `babel` before running it in node.

One way to do that is to use the `externalTranspiler` feature of atom-typescript documented here : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md#can-i-use-an-alternate-transpiler

Comment: Thanks, I will try this~~